# How to combine not like and like?

Tags: mariadb

Using MariadB, how can I combine NOT LIKE and LIKE, so that I can search for the string `FHD` but exclude from the searches if the string `H265` is also present?

This didn't work for me:

```
SELECT  `id` FROM `qualities`.`streams` WHERE quality LIKE '%FHD%' AND NOT LIKE '%H265%';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably got an error like `Incorrect syntax near the keyword LIKE`, because each of the ("NOT LIKE" and "LIKE") conditions needs to specify the column is is working on. If so, this should work:

```
SELECT  `id` FROM `qualities`.`streams` WHERE quality LIKE '%FHD%' AND quality NOT LIKE '%H265%';
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, now I understand

Comment: Is it possible to group more than 1 thing in like and not like? I'm finding myself writing very long queries because of this